# Cannot access static files after application is secured

Tags: java, css, spring-boot

For some reason I can't access my CSS and JS files. What's going on?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Order matters. All permissions must be before the .anyRequest().authenticated()